# ISQLiteConnection::Insert returns number of rows inserted

Tags: mvvmcross

ISQLiteConnection::Insert returns number of rows inserted
I would have expected to return the id of the newly inserted row.

how to retrieve the id?

Answer (score 0):

The core sqlite-net repo (and so the documentation) is still from https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#synchronous-api - but I think this documentation is out of date now.

For an automatic key, the way to get the inserted Id is to look at the Id column after insertion

```
var s = new Person() { Name = "Foo" };
db.Insert(s);
Mvx.Trace("{0} is id for {1}", s.Id, s.Name);
```

You can see this set in the source code at: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/SharedFile/SQLiteNet.cs#L1340

```
        if (map.HasAutoIncPK)
        {
            var id = SQLite3.LastInsertRowid(Handle);
            map.SetAutoIncPK(obj, id);
        }
```

If anyone does want to assist Frank with updating the documentation then please do!

Comment: gee, I saw the function returning number of rows instead of id and I didn't look to the object